# SQL : Records with highest value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a list of marks like in the table below

[image]

would like to get a result like the below. The result should give the records of student with maximum mark and the Record ID

[image]

Comment: OK, what have you attempted?

Comment: I tried Rank() and Group BY

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description recommends, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: version is updated

Comment: @vishnusomanath, Just post your query, And we will try to give the corrected version. Perhaps you dont need GROUP BY when using RANK.

Answer (score 1):

**schema of table with rows values**

```sql
create table notes(RecordID int,Students varchar(255), Marks int);
insert into notes values (1, 'Vladimer', 78),(2, 'Vladimer', 40),(3, 'Vladimer', 64),(4, 'Paul', 99),(5, 'Paul', 86),(6, 'Paul', 65),(7, 'Mathew', 76),(8, 'Mathew', 88),(9, 'Mathew', 65);
```

You could simply use `sub-query`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM notes n
WHERE Marks = (SELECT MAX(Marks) FROM notes WHERE Students = n.Students)
```

other way using `top`:

```sql
select * 
from notes n 
where RecordID = (select top 1 RecordID 
                    from notes 
                    where Students  = n.Students  
                    order by Marks DESC);
```

Another approach with [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and `PARTITION BY Students ORDER BY Marks DESC`

```sql
SELECT N.RecordID, N.Students, N.Marks FROM 
(
    SELECT n.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Students ORDER BY Marks DESC) AS rnk FROM notes n
) N
WHERE N.rnk = 1
order by N.RecordID
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

If you want the top mark per student:

```
select top(1) row with ties *
from marks
order by row_number() over (partition by student order by mark desc);
```

If you wanted the top n results, e.g. the top 3, (but you don't, as we can clearly see from the expected result you are showing):

```
select top(3) row with ties
from marks
order by mark desc;
```

If you want the top n students, e.g. the top 3:

```
select top(3) row with ties
from ( <first query> ) top_marks
order by mark desc;
```

There exist other options of course. In order to get the top mark per student, you could use `NOT EXISTS` for instance to make sure there exists no row with a better mark for the student:

```
select *
from marks
where not exists
(
  select null
  from marks better
  where better.student = marks.student
  and better.mark > marks.mark
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got the answer.

```
SELECT RecordID, 
           Students, 
           Marks, 
           RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Students ORDER BY Marks DESC) Rank
    FROM Table
    ORDER BY Students, 
             Rank;
```

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-sql-rank-functions/

Comment: This doesn't give you the result you were asking for, though.